# KeyboardAvoidingView + ListView

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

I have a submission form interface，use `ListView` Component, and the row contain `TextInput` Component, I want to user `KeyboardAvoidingView` to avoid The Keyboard `cover` the TextInput in row , But it is not working,The row does not move up.

my code:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}  behavior='padding'>
            <ListView
                dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow = {this._renderRow.bind(this)}
                onEndReachedThreshold = {0}
                overflow = 'hidden'
                keyboardDismissMode = 'on-drag'
                removeClippedSubviews = {true}
            />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one module which I have used for keyboard issue: https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

You can use it same way:

```
import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView extraHeight={130}>
          // your code here
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Let me know if face any issue to use it.

Comment: in document they had mentioned that _Android natively has this feature, you can easily enable it by setting windowSoftInputMode in AndroidManifest.xml_ and from their module they support few features which are also listed