# KeyboardAwareScrollView Works For iOS But Not For Android And Seems To Mess Up Layout On Android

Tags: react-native, keyboard, scrollview

I'm very new to React-Native and have been playing around with trying to automatically adjust the views based on the keyboard showing or disappearing.

I have employed the  tag (and module) and it works exactly the way it is supposed to on the iOS simulator, but on the android emulator it doesn't show my entire logo and the textFields are nowhere to be found. The code is the same in both the index files for android and iOS so i'm a bit stuck on this one. Images below:

====== **iOS Screenshot** ======

[iOS Simulator Login Screen Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbtgc.png)

====== **Android Emulator Screensho** ======

[Android Emulator Login Screen Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vjCV.png)

Is there something that i'm doing wrong or missing?

Below is my code for the login/launch/home screen **including my styling/stylesheets.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, Image, StatusBar, ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidingView, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import TextField from 'react-native-md-textinput';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

let window = Dimensions.get('window');

class MainApp extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {}
  }

  render(){
    return (

      <View style={styles.contentContainerStyle}>

          <StatusBar barStyle = "light-content" hidden = {false} />

          <KeyboardAwareScrollView extraHeight={80}>

            <Image style={styles.ctfLondonLogoStyle} source={require('../images/ctflondon.png')}/>

            <View style={styles.usernameTextFieldPositioningStyle}>
              <TextField style={styles.textFieldStyles}
                dense={true}
                label='Username'
                labelColor='white'
                highlightColor='white'
                borderColor='white'
                fontSize={13}
                selectionColor='white'
              />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.passwordTextFieldPositioningStyle}>
              <TextField
                dense={true}
                label='Password'
                labelColor='white'
                highlightColor='white'
                borderColor='white'
                fontSize={13}
                selectionColor='white'
                secureTextEntry={true}
              />
            </View>

          </KeyboardAwareScrollView>

      </View>
    )
  }

}


const styles = {

  contentContainerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(190,0,39,0.7)'
  },

  mainScrollViewStyle: {

  },

  ctfLondonLogoStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    top: 150,
    width: 150,
    height: 150
  },

  textFieldStyles: {
    width: 150,
    height: 35,
    color: 'white'
  },

  usernameTextFieldPositioningStyle: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: window.width * 0.55,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    top: 180
  },

  passwordTextFieldPositioningStyle: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: window.width * 0.55,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    top: 200
  }

};

export default MainApp;
```

Comment: check other option mentioned in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365870/keyboardavoidingview-listview

Comment: @JigarShah thanks a lot. I actually tried that module before and it works for iOS correctly but it did nothing on android.

I've updated my code and added screenshots from both iOS and Android because i'm getting different results in the view

Comment: Upon further testing I've discovered the issue is occurring because i'm using KeyboardAwareScrollView, when I change the KeyboardAwareScrollView to a normal view the whole image appears along with the textfields. any ideas are welcome :-) @JigarShah

Comment: try by adjusting `extraHeight` or styling . This module works for me in both platform ,so I'm sure that, it should be styling issue. Fly... I have `extraHeight={130}`.

Comment: Which version of React Native are you using? According to the docs RN >= 0.46 is needed: https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view#android-support